# How does an increased amplitude affect nerve conduction velocity?

Tags: neuroscience, action-potential

My professor said that increasing the amplitude (the amount of depolarization e.g. depolarizing from -80 mV instead of -50 mV) leads to a greater conduction velocity.

Comment: Do you mean that larger-amplitude action potentials have larger speeds? In that case your example is incorrect, as an action potential generated from a resting potential of -80 mV has a larger amplitude than an action potential generated from a resting membrane potential of -50 mV.

Comment: @AliceD yes that's what I mean, -80mV has a larger amplitude and will have a greater conduction velocity through the neuron as compared to a 50mV resting potential. Why is this?